# Asynchronous callback along a D3 chain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Edit: *I rewrote the entire question to more concisely address the issue***

Is it possible to get information out of asynchronous callback functions along a D3 chain?

For example, I'm trying to display a list of files and their content:

with these text files...

```
$ cat f1.txt
ABC

$ cat f2.txt
DEF

$ cat f3.txt
GHI
```

...I'm trying to make this:

```
f1.txt -- ABC
f2.txt -- DEF
f3.txt -- GHI
```

Since reading a file is asyncronous, I can't use `d3.text` in this `.text` call:

```
var files = [ 'f1.txt', 'f2.txt', 'f3.txt' ];

d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
   .data(files)
   .enter()
   .append("p")
   .text( function(d){ return d + " -- <and its content>" } );
```

Is it possible to get `d`'s contents where I currently have "`and its contents`"?

Comment: Can you read the contents with an xhr request?

Comment: I thought there might be something more in the spirit of D3

Comment: Ideally the table content would be bound to the file content.. so updates to the file would update the table. I realize that might be pushing it though..

Comment: Javascript doesn't allow access to the filesystem, so you need to send of a request to something that can and returns the contents.

Comment: What about `d3.text`? The problem I'm having with that is that it only seems to support giving me access to the text in its callback function.. can't seem to get the text back into the scope where I need it.

Comment: Yes -- all of these functions are asynchronous, so you have to do everything you want to do with the result in the callback.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: What if the I need the result later on in the chain of method call? See updated question

Comment: You could set a global variable, but you would have to make sure that the code is executed in the order you require.